# A word for "just before a position"

Tags: phrase-request

Suppose there is a sequence like

> A B C D E

What is the phrase for the positional relation between B and C (for example)

- B is before C
- B is next to C
- B precedes C

I need to emphasize there is not other intervening elements between

Comment: I would say "immediately next to" or "immediately before"

Answer (score 1):

You should say B precedes C.

This usage does not suggest any causal relationship between B and C.

transitive verb
1
:  to surpass in rank, dignity, or importance
2
:  to be, go, or come ahead or in front of
3
:  to be earlier than
4
:  to cause to be preceded :  preface
intransitive verb
:  to go or come before

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/precede

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

- C is adjacent to D
- C adjoins D

Comment: Neither of these fully describes the sequence: C may be either immediately before or immediately after D.

Comment: @Irfan434 - Your answer might be more useful if you were to explain why you chose _adjacent_ and _adjoin._